# How to change all sorts of accents and special characters from a path in Swift?

Tags: string, cocoa, swift

Hey what's up everyone?

I have a simple app to display the file size of files selected by users. The problem is that when the file is located within a folder that has spaces in the folder name or special characters like accents (á é ç) the file path uses different symbols and then I can't get the file size.

The folder is: /Users/home/Checking/First Box

This is my code and the output:

```
var path = url.absoluteString?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil)
var filePath = path
        var attr:NSDictionary? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath!, error: nil)
        if let _attr = attr {
            fileSize = _attr.fileSize();

        }
        println(fileSize)
        println(filePath!)
```

And the output is nil for the file size and /Users/home/Checking/First%20Box  for the file path.

Also if I select a folder with accent on its name like /Users/home/Checking/Café the output for the path will be /Users/home/Checking/Cafe%CC%81

One solution, which is the one I am using using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString but this adds a lot of line to the code since there are many characters with accent throughout the languages around the world and I was wondering if there's another more simple way to do this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a wrong (and too complicated) method
to convert a file URL to a path.

Example:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/ä/ö/ü")!
println(url.absoluteString!)  // file:///a%CC%88/o%CC%88/u%CC%88
println(url.path!)            // /ä/ö/ü
```

As you see, `.absoluteString` returns a HTML string with percent escapes,
whereas `.path` returns the file path. So your code should look like this:

```
if let filePath = url.path {
    println(filePath)
    if let attr : NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(filePath, error: nil)  {
        let fileSize = attr.fileSize();
        println(fileSize)
        // ...
    }
}
```